# How to get @Configuration files in Spring to run

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

I'm writing a micro service using dependency injection, and I have a Java class annotated with `@Configuration` which creates all my beans. However, my autowired fields are not detecting the beans. How do I get my `@Configuration` class to run before the application starts?

I tried annotating the classes with the Autowired fields as `@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)`, but this didn't work.

My spring configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return ...
    }


    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

I expect the Configuration file to be run and the beans injected, but the beans are not being detected.

There's no main method, since I'm writing this in a service which is created using dependency injection in another service. I'm not sure where I'd tell my application to use my Config file.

Answer (score 0):

probably place a `@EnableConfigurationProperties( {Config.class})` above your @SpringBootApplication main class.